# Two find commands comparison

Tags: bash, shell, find

Recently I received this `find` one-liner, but I'm not able to explain where the difference of the below two comes from:

#### Example 1

```
[root@centos share]# find . -exec grep -i "madis" {} /dev/null \;

./names:Madison Randy:300:Product Development
```

#### Example 2

```
[root@centos share]# find . -exec grep -i "madis" {} \;

Madison Randy:300:Product Development
```

As you can see, in the first one there is the specific file this string derives from and so far I'm really not able to find out why this is happening.

Answer (score 17):

You are telling grep to search 2 locations. grep only shows the full location if multiple locations are searched.

For example

```
touch /tmp/herp /tmp/derp
cd /tmp
echo "foo" > herp
echo "foo" > derp
```

Notice how if I search just 1 file, grep omits the file name

```
grep -i "foo" /tmp/herp
foo
```

But if I specify multiple search locations, grep says where it found each match

```
grep -i "foo" herp derp
/tmp/derp:foo
/tmp/herp:foo
```

Adding the `/dev/null` is it tricking grep into printing out the full path, by providing 2 arguments.

Comment: +1 but you forgot to mention the "obvious": "The reason the added file is `/dev/null` is to be sure that whatever is grep-ed won't be found in the (empty) `/dev/null` file, so only the correct locations are outputed"

Comment: But also, by searching `/dev/null` you don't waste any time seaching through a non-empty dummy file. And finally, the intent of searching `/dev/null` is obvious to those familiar with this idiom.

Answer (score 5):

`man grep`:

> -H, --with-filename
>
> Print the file name for each match.  This is the default when there is more than one file to search.

The difference results from grep being called with one or two file arguments in the two cases. Instead of adding `/dev/null` you could call `grep` with the argument `-H`. Maybe the `/dev/null` behaviour is more widely supported.

Comment: `grep -H` is not portable -- the `/dev/null` trick works without GNU grep.

Answer (score 4):

First example is equivalent to running grep over two files for each file found as a result of the `find` expression. For example, if `find` finds three files `a.txt`, `b.txt` and `c.txt` then `grep` will run as

```
grep -i "madis" a.txt /dev/null
grep -i "madis" b.txt /dev/null 
grep -i "madis" c.txt /dev/null
```

To which `grep` will show the filename for which the output matches. Since nothing will match the /dev/null, it is guaranteed that the filename of the first file will be printed if it matches.

Whereas, the second example is equivalent of

```
grep -i "madis" a.txt
grep -i "madis" b.txt 
grep -i "madis" c.txt
```

In which case the filename will not be printed for matches as there is just one argument.